# Apple TV - How to parse/read the Apple TV Photo Database file?

Tags: itunes, screensaver, appletv

I've used iTunes 11.0.2 "File->Home Sharing->Choose Photos to Share with Apple TV" to select a directory with 4000 photos. Unfortunately, only a few (100-ish?) are in the random rotation on the Screen Saver on Apple TV.

I've found a file called "Apple TV Photo Database" in the directory that I shared and I'd like to parse it to find out how it is working and exactly how many photos are in the cache. Maybe I can rewrite the file and trick Apple TV to rotate through more of them, or maybe I'll just understand better what is going on.

Anybody know where the layout of the file is, or what tools know how to parse and read the file? (Or of another way to get more photos into the screen saver random rotation?)